# gulp-sass npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, node-sass

Im trying to install gulp-sass from terminal window in visual studio code.

other dependencies like autoprefixer, concat etc install without a problem, but gulp-sass keeps giving me this error.

```
> node-sass@4.9.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

sh: node: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Im running VSC on a mac.

Any help please? I am completely new at all this btw, no programming background, just front end dev.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What’s the command you are running for the install?

Comment: Unable to save binary /home/hh/buildtool/udacity/wittr/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/hh/buildtool/udacity/wittr/node_modules/node-sass/vendor    I have same version and close kind of failure.  My concern is that is works with docker

Comment: This worked for me:   npm install --unsafe-perm=true

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And I found this solution:

```
sudo npm install -g node-sass@4.5.3 --unsafe-perm = true --allow-root
```

I just changed part of the code:

```
sudo npm install gulp-sass --unsafe-perm = true --allow-root
```

It worked for me.

Comment: npm install -g node-sass@4.5.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root  
This one did work for me

Answer (score 0):

[`npm install -g node-sass@4.5.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`]

This one did work for me to install the package but it failed again when I start the application

I tried with the [`yarn install`] instead of [`npm install`]
The app started successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I get the same solution as you. and I tried searching on the internet and I found here http://relaxitblog.com/?p=611
then after that I installed: sudo npm install gulp-sass
after that: npm audit fix
success

Comment: I removed everything (format actually coz it was due) then re-installed with homebrew.... fixed eveything.. no need for sudo also